# importing a car from Spain to Georgia (country)

Tags: spain, vehicle-registration, imports, turkish-citizens

for example, a turkish citizen living in georgia (country) will import a car from Spain to georgia (country). the car will come via Hungary to have the Hungarian export registration number plates issued (Z-***** in format)

the car will then get georgian registration number plates in rustavi. how much does it charge for importing a car from Spain to georgia (country)? (including hungarian export registration number plate cost and taxes)

the turkish citizen will bring the car to georgia via hungary by driving it, not by ship.

for the tax the engine displacement of the car is: 3,598 cc.